# How to resolve 'Xpage class could not be found' after build

Tags: java, jvm, xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

The Xpages app is a few years old, but now, any updates to an existing Xpage breaks it with a browser message:

> HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception

The xpages_exec log shows:

> com.ibm.xsp.page.PageNotFoundException: Could not create the page
>   /Cards.xsp because the class xsp.Cards could not be found. Please
>   check your spelling.

This occurs even if simply resaving a working Xpage; the Xpage class will no longer be found.  Same if simply renaming or copying an Xpage.  I have used Domino Designer on other workstations with the same results on the server.

Perhaps this is a JVM run time issue? The server console shows the JVM version:

```
JVM: Java Virtual Machine initialized.
Java runtime version: 8.0.5.6 - pwa6480sr5fp6-20171124_02(SR5 FP6)
JVM version: JRE 1.8.0 Windows Server 2008 R2 amd64-64 20171122_371101 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) OpenJ9 - 8e3c85d OMR - 713f08e IBM - c041ee8
```

The Domino Designer Java compiler workspace settings **JDK compliance level is set to 1.5** with JRE 1.6 installed.

How might I determine why after new build of an Xpage causes the Xpage class to no longer be found?

UPDATE: from the xpages exec log:

```
1/16/20 12:33 PM: Exception Thrown
com.ibm.xsp.page.PageNotFoundException: Could not create the page /Cards.xsp because the class xsp.Cards could not be found. Please check your spelling.
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.getClassForPageName(CompiledPageDriver.java:174)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.loadPage(CompiledPageDriver.java:61)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:499)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:250)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:159)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class xsp.Cards in NSF
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:503)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:924)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:869)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:209)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:219)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.Application.loadClass(Application.java:708)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ApplicationFacesClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationFacesClassLoader.java:54)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.getClassForPageName(CompiledPageDriver.java:169)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xsp.Cards
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:609)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:476)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Is automatic build disabled? And have you built the project?

Comment: Yes, automatic build is on, and I have cleaned and built the project.  That's when the page no longer works.

Comment: Does the file path in "Context Path" for the PageNotFoundException error in the XPages log file match the file path of your nsf?

Comment: The Context Path is not shown for the xsp class not found error, unlike other Xpage errors that also appear in the log.  I have updated the question with a more detailed log.

Comment: Switching to Package Explorer view showed that an extension library was missing that was in the xsp.properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Domino Designer**, switch to the **Package Explorer** view, and look for any errors.  In the case above, the library **com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library** was included in the **xsp.properties** file but not found.  Remove the dependency from xsp.properties or make sure the library is installed or in the build path.